# iPod touch connects to WiFi but cannot reach internet sites. Any ideas?

Tags: ipod-touch

My little  ten-year-old-or-so iPod Touch cannot, AFAICT, get to any internet site.  Neither by browser nor by apps.  The problem does not seem to be connecting to WiFi.  I select a network, give it the password, wait a few seconds, and then at least it thinks it connects to the network.  It gives a checkmark next to the network name and no error messages.  But then I cannot get to any internet site.  Every site I try gives a message like "Cannot connect to ..." or "Server not available ..."  This is not a problem specific to my home WiFi; I have tried this on four different WiFi networks, all giving the same result.  I have tried some of the common solutions to the problem of not connecting to a network in the first place (let me repeat, that is not the problem).  Other than that, I don't know what to do.  Any ideas?

One more thing: The last time I tried to connect was a couple of months ago and it worked fine.   No idea what could have changed in the meantime.

Comment: Try turning Airplane Mode on then off to reset DNS.  If that fails to work, trying resetting Network Settings in Settings.  You will need to reset your network settings if you do this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This question belongs in Ask Different

Comment: @John  Would be happy to use that other ask if someone told me what it was.  "iPod touch" is a category for this site, I noticed.

Comment: Ask Different is a site here like Super User.   Ask Different is for Apple. I am not able to migrate your question but you could delete it here and re-ask in the Apple site known as Ask Different.

Comment: You might be running afoul of cert expiration date checks. First make sure your date and time are set correctly. Then make sure you have the latest version of iOS for that device, and any other updates from Apple (so you have the latest root CA certs Apple ever provided for that model). Then (somehow?) look to see what the root CA cert expiration dates are. Can you connect to non-secure sites like http://httpforever.com/ ?